# Gmail add-on throws 'Library with identifier is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or maybe you don't have read access?)' after I made new deployment

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

With the updated code changes, I've created a new deployment version with new version number which I usually do to deploy my Gmail add-on. But this time, after deployment, when I'm doing authentication with the third party, I'm getting an error:

```
Library with identifier SetmoreForGmail is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or maybe you don't have read access?)
```

[image: error]

Comment: So you seem to be missing a library.  Check Resources menu in Script Editor?

Comment: Can you confirm the library you are using is indeed installed? @RajeshThulasingam

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting is due to the fact that the library with the  `SetmoreForGmail`is missing.

You just need to go to your project's libraries and (re)add it in order for the script to work as expected.

[image]

**Reference**

- [Apps Script Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries).